# How to use two shaders to render two objects in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to use two different shader programs in order to render two different objects.

I have two vertex shaders with the same input parameters, and two fragment shaders, where one of them is set to color the fragments red.

When trying to get the attribute location of color in the `loadPlainShader`, I get a `GL_INVALID_INDEX` as a return.

Why can't OpenGL find the color attribute the second time, even though the vertex shaders are practically alike?

I have included my code, and it is also available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8o98ovh8pzubxiw/XGbO-IGQsW/stackoverflow

**What I am trying**

From main I'm trying to first load the two shader programs:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  ... GLUT and GLEW initilization ...
    loadPlainShader();
    loadShader();
    loadGeometry();

    glutMainLoop();
 }
```

**loadPlainShader()**

```
 void loadPlainShader(){
    plainShader = InitShader("plain-shader.vert", "plain-shader.frag", "fragColor");
    plainProjUniform = glGetUniformLocation(plainShader, "projection");
    plainModelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(plainShader, "modelView");
    plainColorAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(plainShader, "color");
    plainPositionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(plainShader, "position");
 }
```

**loadShader()**

```
 void loadShader(){
    shaderProgram = InitShader("color-shader.vert",  "color-shader.frag", "fragColor");
    projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
    modelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modelView");
    colorAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    positionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
 }
```

**initShader()**

```
 GLuint InitShader(const char* vShaderFile, const char* fShaderFile, const char* outputAttributeName) {
    struct Shader {
       const char*  filename;
       GLenum       type;
       GLchar*      source;
    }  shaders[2] = {
       { vShaderFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, NULL },
       { fShaderFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
       Shader& s = shaders[i];
       s.source = readShaderSource( s.filename );
       if ( shaders[i].source == NULL ) {
          std::cerr << "Failed to read " << s.filename << std::endl;
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
       }
       GLuint shader = glCreateShader( s.type );
       glShaderSource( shader, 1, (const GLchar**) &s.source, NULL );
       glCompileShader( shader );

       GLint  compiled;
       glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );
       if ( !compiled ) {
          std::cerr << s.filename << " failed to compile:" << std::endl;
          GLint  logSize;
          glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize );
          char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
          glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
          std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
          delete [] logMsg;

          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
       }

       delete [] s.source;

       glAttachShader( program, shader );
    }

    /* Link output */
    glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, outputAttributeName);

    /* link  and error check */
    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint  linked;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );
    if ( !linked ) {
       std::cerr << "Shader program failed to link" << std::endl;
       GLint  logSize;
       glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize);
       char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
       glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
       std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
       delete [] logMsg;

       exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    /* use program object */
    glUseProgram(program);
    return program;
 }
```

**loadGeometry()**

```
 void loadGeometry() {
    vec3 color(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    vec3 colorR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertex rectangleData[rectangleSize] = {
       { vec2(-5.0, -5.0 ), color },
       { vec2(-5.0,  5.0 ), color },
       { vec2( 8.0,  5.0 ), color },
       { vec2( 8.0, -5.0 ), color }
    };

    Vertex triangleData[triangleSize] = {
       { vec2(2.0, 2.0 ), vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)},
       { vec2(5.0,  2.0 ), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) },
       { vec2( 3.5,  5.0 ), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) }
    };
    rectangleVertexArrayBuffer = loadBufferData(rectangleData, rectangleSize);
    triangleVertexArrayBuffer = loadPlainBufferData(triangleData, triangleSize);
 }
```

**loadBufferData**

```
GLuint loadBufferData(Vertex* vertices, int vertexCount) {
   GLuint vertexArrayObject;

   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
   glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

   GLuint vertexBuffer;
   glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);
   glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttribute  , 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)sizeof(vec2));

   return vertexArrayObject;
}
```

**loadPlainBufferData**

```
GLuint loadPlainBufferData(Vertex* vertices, int vertexCount) {
   GLuint vertexArrayObject;

   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
   glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

   GLuint vertexBuffer;
   glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(plainPositionAttribute);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(plainColorAttribute);
   glVertexAttribPointer(plainPositionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(plainColorAttribute  , 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)sizeof(vec2));

   return vertexArrayObject;
}
```

**My display function**

```
void display() {    
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

   mat4 projection = Ortho2D(-15.0f, 15.0f, -10.0f, 15.0f);
   glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, projection);

   mat4 modelViewRec;
   mat4 modelViewTri;

   modelViewRec = RotateZ(45) * modelViewRec;

   // render rectangle
   glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelViewRec);
   glBindVertexArray(rectangleVertexArrayBuffer);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, rectangleSize);

   modelViewTri = Translate(6,7,0) * modelViewTri;

   glUseProgram(plainShader);

   // render triangle
   glUniformMatrix4fv(plainModelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelViewTri);
   glBindVertexArray(triangleVertexArrayBuffer);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangleSize);

   glutSwapBuffers();

   Angel::CheckError();
}
```

**color-shader vertex shader and plain-shader vertex shader (identical)**

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec4 colorV;

void main (void)
{
   colorV = vec4(color, 1.0);
   gl_Position = projection * modelView * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Plainshader fragment shader**

```
#version 150

in vec4 colorV;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

**color-shader fragment shader**

```
#version 150

in vec4 colorV;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = colorV;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be more helpful to show the shaders in this case.

Comment: No, no, no. `GL_INVALID_INDEX` is **0xFFFFFFFF**, but that is not actually what `glGetAttribLocation (...)` is returning. It is returning a *signed* integer: **-1**, which indicates that there is no ***active*** attribute in your GLSL program by that name. The only way to explain why this is the case is if you show your actual shaders.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I have added the vertex and fragment shaders now.

Comment: That's a nice point Andon! If i use the colorV in the fragment shader, there is no longer an error. Although it does not draw the second object on the screen?

Comment: The second shader works now. If i assign the shader to be used as the plain shader and draw both objects they appear. But if i switch to another shaderprogram using glUseProgram(..) it won't draw the second object.

Comment: Got it working. I forgot i had to sent the projection uniform again, after applying glUseProgram(..). Thank you Andon and user1118321